# Create a Jenkins job running an Ansible script through the API

Tags: python, jenkins, ansible

I have a python script that creates a jenkins job, as below

```
def create_jenkins_job(self):
    jenk = jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_url, username=jenkins_user, password=jenkins_token)

    jobs = jenk.create_job('test2', jenkins.EMPTY_CONFIG_XML)
    return True
```

This successfully creates an empty job as expected. I'm trying to have this job run an Ansible playbook, held locally in the same directory. The ansible plugin is already installed on the jenkins instance. Is it possible to create a job with the ansible parameter and pass the playbook to it?

Comment: You would do that inside the `Jenkinsfile` associated with the job that your Python script is invoking. Documentation exists for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my understanding you want to do two things:

1. create a job which is having ansible plugin build step.
2. run the job passing(uploading) a local playbook and run the job using ansible plugin

if it is the case, then here is my answer:
1:

- You can use `copy_job(from_job, to_job)` method where `from_job` is sample job already present having a file parameter (lets say PLAYBOOK) and build step as to run the uploaded playbook.
- please refer using File Parameter([How to use file parameter in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224691/how-to-use-file-parameter-in-jenkins))
- You can refer the below link how to trigger the build with file parameter using python.([Triggering parameterized build using jenkinsapi in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530616/triggering-parameterized-build-using-jenkinsapi-in-python))

I know creating a sample job and copying it is not a good solution but it would work.
But     `jobs = jenk.create_job('test2', jenkins.EMPTY_CONFIG_XML)` is going to create an empty job which wont be having any pre-configuration. So we need some configuration(any existing job's **config.xml**) to pre-configure the job using python-jenkins api.